# Save object that threw warning using tryCatch

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `tryCatch` to return the evaluated expression *as well as* the warning it generates. I'd also like to do this without evaluating the expression twice.
Here's a very simple example:

```
x <- -1
info <- tryCatch(sqrt(x),
                 error = function(e) e
                 warning = function(w) w)
```

Here `info` ends up being the caught warning, where i'd also like to get the `NaN` produced by `sqrt(x)`.

The application of this is a model that I'm fitting, where I'd like to know what warnings popped up, but I also only want to evaluate the model once. If I could fit it twice, I could check if info was a warning and then just refit it, but fitting the model twice is prohibitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `demo(error.catching)`, which provides the following

```
##' Catch *and* save both errors and warnings, and in the case of
##' a warning, also keep the computed result.
##'
##' @title tryCatch both warnings (with value) and errors
##' @param expr an \R expression to evaluate
##' @return a list with 'value' and 'warning', where
##'   'value' may be an error caught.
##' @author Martin Maechler;
##' Copyright (C) 2010-2012  The R Core Team
tryCatch.W.E <- function(expr)
{
    W <- NULL
    w.handler <- function(w){ # warning handler
      W <<- w
      invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
    }
    list(value = withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) e),
                                   warning = w.handler),
       warning = W)
}
```

In your example case

```
tryCatch.W.E(sqrt(-1))
#> $value
#> [1] NaN
#> 
#> $warning
#> <simpleWarning in sqrt(-1): NaNs produced>
```